# c++, functions of a particular class do not return me updated values when I access them from another class

Tags: c++, sockets, polymorphism, ns-3

I have three classes `tcp-socket-base`, `tp-tx-buffer` and `mptcp-socketbase`. Tcp-tx-buffer class variables returns `0` when accessed via mptcp-socketbase class. Polymorphism exists, when there is a call to `Availablewindow ()` it first calls to mptcp-socketbase class version then tcp-socket-base class version. Classes are big but here just mentioning relevant functions and statements. Throughout the program `std::cout` returns me.

```
 inflight 0 
 HeadSequence () 0
```

Classses are give below
`tcp-socket-base.h`

```
#include "tcp-tx-buffer.h"
#include "ns3/tcp-socket.h"

//forward declations
class MpTcpSocketBase;
class TcpTxBuffer;
class TcpSocketBase : public TcpSocket
{   
public:
 TcpSocketBase (void);
 TcpSocketBase (const TcpSocketBase& sock);
 virtual ~TcpSocketBase (void);

 virtual uint32_t UnAckDataCount (void) const;
 virtual uint32_t AvailableWindow (void) const;

protected:
 friend class MpTcpSocketBase;
 friend class MpTcpSubflow;

Ptr<TcpTxBuffer> m_txBuffer {0}; //!< Tx buffer
}
```

`Tcp-socket-base.cc`

```
 #include "tcp-socket-base.h"
 #include "tcp-tx-buffer.h"
 #include "mptcp-socket-base.h"

 TcpSocketBase::TcpSocketBase (void)
   : TcpSocket ()
 {
   NS_LOG_FUNCTION (this);
   m_txBuffer = CreateObject<TcpTxBuffer> ();
 }

 TcpSocketBase::TcpSocketBase (const TcpSocketBase& sock)
   : TcpSocket (sock),
     m_txBuffer (sock.m_txBuffer)
 {
    NS_LOG_FUNCTION (this);
    m_txBuffer = CopyObject (sock.m_txBuffer);
 }

 uint32_t
 TcpSocketBase::UnAckDataCount () const
 {
   return m_tcb->m_highTxMark - m_txBuffer->HeadSequence ();
 }

 uint32_t
 TcpSocketBase::AvailableWindow () const
 {
   uint32_t win = Window (); 
   uint32_t inflight = BytesInFlight (); 
   std::cout<<" inflight "<< inflight <<std::endl;
   std::cout<<" HeadSequence ()"<<m_txbuffer->HeadSequence ()<<std::endl;
   return (inflight > win) ? 0 : win - inflight;
 }
```

`tcp-tx-buffer.h`

```
 //forward declations
 class MpTcpSocketBase;
 class TcpTxBuffer : public Object
 {
 public:
 friend class MpTcpSocketBase;
 TcpTxBuffer (uint32_t n = 0);
 virtual ~TcpTxBuffer (void);
 void SetHeadSequence (const SequenceNumber32& seq);
 SequenceNumber32 HeadSequence (void) const; 
 uint32_t BytesInFlight () const;
 private:
 uint32_t m_maxBuffer;  //!< Max number of data bytes in buffer (SND.WND)
 uint32_t m_size;       //!< Size of all data in this buffer 
 }
```

`tcp-tx-buffer.cc`

```
 #include "tcp-tx-buffer.h"

 TcpTxBuffer::TcpTxBuffer (uint32_t n)
 : m_maxBuffer (32768), m_size (0), m_firstByteSeq (n)
 {
 }

 SequenceNumber32
 TcpTxBuffer::HeadSequence (void) const
 {
  return m_firstByteSeq;
 }

 void
 TcpTxBuffer::SetHeadSequence (const SequenceNumber32& seq)
 {
   NS_LOG_FUNCTION (this << seq);
   m_firstByteSeq = seq; 
  }

  uint32_t
  TcpTxBuffer::BytesInFlight () const
  {
   NS_ASSERT_MSG (m_sackedOut + m_lostOut <= m_sentSize,
             "Count of sacked " << m_sackedOut << " and lost " << m_lostOut <<
             " is out of sync with sent list size " << m_sentSize <<
             " " << *this);
   uint32_t leftOut = m_sackedOut + m_lostOut;
   uint32_t retrans = m_retrans;

   NS_LOG_INFO ("Sent size: " << m_sentSize << " leftOut: " << leftOut <<
           " retrans: " << retrans);
   uint32_t in_flight = m_sentSize - leftOut + retrans;

  //uint32_t rfc_in_flight = BytesInFlightRFC (3, segmentSize);
  //NS_ASSERT_MSG(in_flight == rfc_in_flight,
  //              "Calculated: " << in_flight << " RFC: " << rfc_in_flight <<
  //              "Sent size: " << m_sentSize << " leftOut: " << leftOut <<
  //                             " retrans: " << retrans);
   return in_flight;
   }
```

`mptcp-socketbase.h`

```
 #include "ns3/tcp-socket-base.h"
 //forward delcation
 class TcpSocketBase;
 class MpTcpSocketBase :
 public TcpSocketBase
 {
 public:
 MpTcpSocketBase();
 MpTcpSocketBase(const MpTcpSocketBase&);
 MpTcpSocketBase(const TcpSocketBase& sock);
 virtual uint32_t AvailableWindow (void) const;
 }
```

`mptcp-socketbase.cc`

```
 #include "ns3/mptcp-socket-base.h"
 #include "ns3/tcp-tx-buffer.h"

 MpTcpSocketBase::MpTcpSocketBase(const TcpSocketBase& sock) :
 TcpSocketBase(sock)
 {
   NS_LOG_FUNCTION(this);
   NS_LOG_LOGIC("Copying from TcpSocketBase");
 }

 MpTcpSocketBase::MpTcpSocketBase(const MpTcpSocketBase& sock) :
 TcpSocketBase(sock)
 {
   NS_LOG_FUNCTION(this);
   NS_LOG_LOGIC ("Invoked the copy constructor");
 }

  MpTcpSocketBase::MpTcpSocketBase() :
  TcpSocketBase()
  {
     NS_LOG_FUNCTION(this);
  }

   uint32_t
   MpTcpSocketBase::AvailableWindow() const
   {
    NS_LOG_FUNCTION (this);
    uint32_t unack = UnAckDCount(); 
    uint32_t win = Window(); //    it works fine so I show its implementation
    NS_LOG_LOGIC ("UnAckCount=" << unack << ", Win=" << win);
    return (win < unack) ? 0 : (win - unack); 
   }
```

main function;

```
   #include "tcp-tx-buffer.h"
   #include "ns3/tcp-socket.h"
   #include "mptcp-socketbase.h"
    void main () 
            {
              // calling function 
              Ptr<MpTcpSocketBase> mp = CreateObject<MpTcpSocketBase>();
                                    mp->AvailableWindow();
              // if I invoke directly TcpSocketBase class version it returns expected values.
              Ptr<TcpSocketBase> tcp = CreateObject<TcpSocketBase>();
                                 tcp->AvailableWindow();
            }
```

I want updated results to get correct results. Please give me suggestions so that I can get updated values from tcp-tx-buffer class. As I mentioned above all the instances of call to `AvailableWindow()` returns

```
  When invoked from MpTcpSocketBase
  inflight 0 
  HeadSequence () 0

  // when called TcpSocketbase class version, results are. following numbers are given as reference
  inflight 1000
  HeadSequence() 1001
```

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but you class-naming seems... weird. The class `TcpSocketBase` inheriting from `TcpSocket`? Without seeing that inheritance, I would assume that `TcpSocketBase` was the root of the inheritance tree, the original base class so to say. Good naming is very important to help others read and understand your code, and for future maintenance. And with "others" I include yourself in the near future when you start to forget about the details of this code.

Comment: As for your problem, it's going to be *very* hard to help you without a proper [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Also please [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). And I also recommend [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: In particular: 1. You did not describe the expected behavior (why is 0 incorrect?), and 2. you are apparently not happy with the value of `in_flight` but you never show any definition or assignment to it. We don't even know where it comes from.

Comment: I really sorry that I forgot to include `TcpSocket` class. I updated my code, hope this will explain my problem.

Comment: There is really too much code here for us to debug.  Start by removing all the commented out code, and all the calls to NS_LOG.  That will leave you quite a lot of constructors etc that are just defaulting - remove them and default constructed members/bases.  At this point check the code still fails.  Then start moving the definition of functions into the class definition (and checking it still fails).  At this point you should *much* less code for us to inspect.

Comment: Ah!  Not only this not "Minimal", it's not "Complete" either - what is m_lostOut?

Comment: @MartinBonner The "moving functions into definitions" might be difficult judging by how many forward declarations there are.

Comment: @MaxLanghof Yes - but quite a lot of them can be inlined.  For example `HeadSequence()` and `SetHeadSequence` (an even better solution for those would be to make the member variable public, and get rid of the functions entirely - but that's probably a bit *too* much for the OP)

Comment: @evershine Have you tried stepping through the code with a debugger? Your logic in `MpTcpSocketBase::AvailableWindow()` is completely different than the one in `TcpSocketBase`. In fact, I don't see how you even get your printout in the former since it does not even call the latter (or does a similar print)...

Comment: The question is a disaster area, let's just vote to close it and move on.